# Interview on sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, c, sorting

Given a big array which has numbers in range from 1 to 100. What's the best approach to sort it out?

The interviewer was emphasizing on the word *range* ie max number which is present in the array is 100.

Comment: Is this a exam for StackOverflow people :D ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: most likely he's hinting at something like [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: I recommend counting sort, alternatively quicksort.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus QuickSort doesn't make any sense to use here, as it is O(n log n), and given the problem domain, it can be done in O(n)

Comment: "Numbers"  Hmm, more detail: integer or floating point?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
long result[100] = {0};

for (iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    result[*it - 1]++;
}
```

So, you will move linear over your vector and count all numbers there exist. As result you will receive how many 1 you had, how many 2 you had and etc, i.e. it will be as sorted.

UPD: as KillianDS wrote, I mean [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). It's the fast one.

Answer (score 1):

Well since the answer was basically given, example code. There's no need to copy data from the original array; it can be generated from the data in the histogram, called a variant algorithm in the wiki [counting sort variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Variant_algorithms) section:

```
std::vector <size_t> hist(101, 0);      // using index 1 to 100 inclusive
size_t i, j, n;
    for (i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        hist[vec[i]]++;
    i = 0;
    for(j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
        for(n = hist[j]; n; n--)
            vec[i++] = j;
```

Comment: +1 Like the making the array at least 101 to avoid `hist[vec[i]-1]++`; with a history array of 100.  Also good use of `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

May be they wanted to hear about [radix sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Answer (score 0):

It seems counting sort is the most suitable algorithm for this problem, it's O(n), stable, and easy to implement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort